# WordPress Issue : The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

I have created a local WordPress 4.9.8 setup with PHP 7 inside a Fedora running machine.
When I try to upload media into the WordPress admin, it keeps saying that

> The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/

I have given full(777) file permission for content/uploads directory but still, I get the same error.

Finally, I tried to create the directory structure manually and place the media file by myself as follows

> /var/www/html/test-jp/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/1024-xxxxx-logo.png

What may be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may due to the SELinux feature of the Fedora OS.

You can temporarily disable the SELinux in Fedora as follows and test.

Check SELinux status as `sestatus`

If the SELinux is active, the result for the above command will be included.

> Current mode: enforcing

Execute command `sudo setenforce 0` to temporarily disable SELinux

Then if you check `sestatus`

> Current mode: permissive

To re-enable SELinux execute command `sudo setenforce 1`

Answer (score 0):

Check also the owner of the `wp-content/uploads` folder, which should be set to the user under which the web server is running, usually this user is *www-data*.